# i want to ask about checkbox/uncheckbox all

Tags: javascript, ajax, checkbox

**i want to uncheck checkbox "all" when i uncheck checkbok**

```
 $('#All').click(function () {
        var status = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (status) {
            $.each($('input[name="checkbox"]'), function () {
                this.checked = true;
            })
            $('input[name="checkbox"]').attr("checked", "checked");

        } else {
            $('input[name="checkbox"]').removeAttr("checked");
            $.each($('input[name="checkbox"]:checked'), function () {
                this.checked = false;
            })
        }

    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `$('input[name="checkbox"]').attr("checked", "checked");` is can't change all checkbox to checked.Use prop() instead of `.attr()`

```
 $('#All').click(function () {
        var status = $(this).is(":checked");        
        if (status) {
            $('input:checkbox').prop("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```js
$(".all").click(function() 
{
var el=this;
  $(".child").each(function(){    
   $(this).prop("checked",$(el).prop("checked"))   ;
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"  class="all"/>All
<input type="checkbox" class="child"/>one
<input type="checkbox"  class="child"/>two
<input type="checkbox"  class="child"/>three
<input type="checkbox"  class="child"/>four
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('All').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="checkbox"]');
    Array.from(checkboxes).forEach(checkbox => {
        checkbox.checked = this.checked;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected resule,use below option

```
Check All:
('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", "checked");

Uncheck All:
$('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr("checked");
```

$('#All').click(function() {
      var status = $(this).is(":checked");
      if (status) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", "checked");

```
  } else {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').removeAttr("checked");
  }
});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ezBvyG

Answer (score 0):

```
Try with this :
HTML code :

<input type="button" class="check" value="check all" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  1
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  2
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  3

jquery code :
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})
Hope you get your point.
```